# How do I get out of Crystal Peak?

Tags: hollow-knight

I am playing Hollow Knight entirely blind, and I seem to have gotten myself stuck in Crystal Peak. Here's the map as I can see it:

[image: Currently Visible Map]

There are five things on the map which might be exits. Unfortunately, all of them are inaccessible or extremely difficult.

1. The first part of this long cavern is crossable with a super dash, but unfortunately the last part of the cavern has a long vertical drop following by a long width of crystal-covered floor too wide to cross with a dash. You can charge a super dash on top of the adjacent platform, but the resulting way across is blocked by another wall.
2. This is how I first got into the cavern, but it's now at the bottom of a long wide well with overhangs to prevent wall-jumping.
3. A dark passage, blocked. I can see the silhouette of what looks like a toll tower, but I can't interact with it.
4. Only accessible with a high jump that I don't seem to have.
5. A dark passage with a crystal floor. This is the most frustrating, because it seems to be crossable in theory, but it's dark and there's a crystal hunter flying around making it exceedingly difficult to get across.

I may have done things in an unusual order, because I don't have a light source or a double-jump, either of which would make some of these passages accessible.

Abilities I do have: wall jump, dash, super dash, as well as sharpened nail, blade whirl, vengeful soul (ranged magic attack), and downward magic strike (breaks floor). Sorry that I don't recall the precise names of any of them.

(Please make answers as spoiler-free as possible).

Comment: you mentioned some of the items you have and don't have, but could you describe the abilities you've unlocked?  It's been a while since I played but I'm thinking exit 1 is your best bet.  It sounds like you might not realize you can super dash from just standing on the ground (you mention no wall is available for it).  Good news, you don't need a wall for super dash!!

Comment: @PawnInGameOfLife Edited the question.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ How many bosses have you defeated in this area? One of the bosses holds the ability you'll need to get out, and that ability gets you out through exit 1.

Comment: @senpai I have defeated the Crystal Guardian, the only boss that I found, at the bench in the upper part of the map. I also "defeated" the jumping puzzle required to reach the Crystal Heart and get the super dash.

Comment: Good news! I went back to 1 after your comments and got across. The problem was that I didn't realize you could charge the super dash while sliding down a wall (I thought you could only do it while *stationary* on a wall, like with the conveyor belts). I'll update with a screenshot shortly.

Comment: ...you didn't mention Mantis Claw / Wall Climb, which is necessary to perform some crystal dashes to exit the area (by starting them on the wall)... but you'd be unable to access it without Mantis Claw.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To address each of these in order:

1. You can reach this exit with the super dash (aka the Crystal Dash). You can charge a super dash while either standing on the floor or sliding down a wall. With that in combination with some regular platforming, you can get all the way to the end.
2. This is only an entrance, not an exit. It can never be reached from this side.
3. You can only interact with this toll if you have the light, so you cannot go this way.
4. It is quite difficult to get up there without an ability you will get later in the game. Minor spoilers about what's beyond that point:

   > Even if you do get up there, that is not an exit anyway.
5. This area can be a little tricky even if you have the light. I know some speedruns go this way without the light so it is possible, but it would be very frustrating.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I didn't realize that I could charge the super dash while sliding down the wall, but with that bit of knowledge it became easy to get out of exit 1.

Comment: You actually *can* get up to the ledge at (4) without double-jump by not killing the enemy that's there and instead using your nail to bounce off of a pickaxe they throw. imo it's not worth it though because the rest of that area is a lot more difficult without double-jump.

Comment: I've changed the description of that point to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to the earlier answers, you can actually exit the Crystal Peaks back to the Forgotten Crossroads (Exit 2) using wall jump and crystal dash.

From the bottom of the pit, wall jump up the right-hand wall until you reach an impassable overhang. From the highest point on the wall you can reach, use the crystal dash to transfer to the left-hand wall. Immediately after landing on the left wall, start wall jumping up, or you'll fall to the bottom of the pit again. Keep wall jumping to the top!

Look out for a secret li'l area on the right-hand side, half-way up the pit. IIRC, you can get a rancid egg here.

Comment: Welcome to arqade.se! Take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance. Pretty nice and precise first answer, good job ^^